# Abrir iframe en ventana nueva

Tags: html, css

tengo este codigo que es de un widget de criptos, para saber los valores,

```
<div style="height:274px; background-color: #1D2330; opacity: 0.9; overflow:hidden; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #282E3B; border-radius: 4px; text-align: right; line-height:14px; font-size: 12px; font-feature-settings: normal; text-size-adjust: 100%; box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 0 0 #262B38; padding: 0px; margin: 0; width: 100%;">
<div style="height:354px; padding:0px; margin:0px; width: 100%;"><iframe src="https://widget.coinlib.io/widget?type=full_v2&theme=dark&cnt=5&pref_coin_id=1505&graph=no" width="100%" height="350px" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" style="border:0;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe></div>
            </div>
```

pero al darle click, abre la pagina en la misma ventana, yo quisiera que abra en una ventana a parte, ya probé con target=_blank / _top etc, varios codigos y no logro que funcione, siempre que le doy click se abre la pagina en la misma ventana..
No se como hacer para que sea en una ventana nueva, si me pueden ayudar agradeceré su ayuda..aguardo sus comentarios, saludos

Comment: Usa una etiqueta <a> en lugar de <iframe> y añade el target="_blank"

Comment: Hola como estas, no funciona, porque si cambio el iframe por el a, directamente no se carga el widget...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que debes hacer, es poner una etiqueta que te redireccione a la nueva ventana en blanco:

[image: Explicacion]

y en la ventana que se abre, ahí debes poner el iframe para que se cargue el contenido.

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Código como texto por favor

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).